# JDBC Problem wth select where query

Tags: java, jdbc

My Code:

```
con = jdbc.connect();
        System.out.println("status of con"+con);
String query = " select * from BmgCPUTotalUsage where CPUserID='"+CPUserID+"' and MessageTypeID='"+MessageTypeID+"'";
        System.out.println(query);
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    System.out.println(result);
    int QuotaUsed=result.getInt("QuotaUsed");
```

Output:

```
   status of concom.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@182600f
     select QuotaUsed from BmgCPUTotalUsage where CPUserID='msdp' and MessageTypeID='SMS'
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@16e1dd8
    java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set.
```

Can anybody please say me how can I remove this exception.and fetch the QuotaUsed from the table.where QuotaUsed  is an integer.

Comment: Have you ever experienced how it is to accept an answer? Try it now. It does wonders. Believe me.

Answer (score 8):

You really need to do more reading of the [JDBC Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), but briefly, try this:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
if (resultSet.next() {
    int quotaUsed = resultSet.getInt("QuotaUsed"); 
}
```